# chef: The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x' can't be established

Tags: chef, knife

I'm running knife bootstrap command I'm getting following error

> Connecting to x.x.x.x WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged
>   into stdout The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x ()' can't be
>   established. fingerprint is
>   SHA256:X6Wt8NPOahi/HJ1r7162opJxuhaK7vBklCA7f1wkSUI.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting ? (Y/N)

if I input Y it works but I want to run this command without prompting an input; how can I do that?

my command

```
knife bootstrap x.x.x.x -x root -N node1 --sudo '--run-list=chef-client,role[access]' -E test -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive this warning because the ssh host key for the remote host is not known to your user locally, and not stored in the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

If you're bringing up a new server you can use `ssh-keyscan` to get its host keys and store them away in a file. A trivial example:

```
ssh-keyscan HOSTNAME >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The command has many options suitable for automation, such as passing a list of hostnames to scan; read its man page to see what options are available to you.